# couldn't use lambda expression to create the ThreadLocal class

Tags: java, java-8

I have the below code

```
      ThreadLocal<Map<String, Service<Request, Response>>> connectinonMapThread = new ThreadLocal<Map<String, Service<Request, Response>>>() {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, Service<Request, Response>> initialValue() {
            return new HashMap<String, Service<Request, Response>>();
        }
    };
```

I want to write it using lambda expression like below -

```
ThreadLocal<Map<String, Service<Request, Response>>> connectinonMapThread2 = new ThreadLocal<Map<String, Service<Request, Response>>>(() -> new HashMap<String, Service<Request, Response>>());
```

I tried another one.

```
ThreadLocal<Map<String, Service<Request, Response>>> connectinonMapThread2 = initialValue() -> {

            return new HashMap<String, Service<Request, Response>>();
    };
```

But I am getting compilation error. But the IntelliJ Idea suggests this could be written as lambda expression.

[image: Intellij Idea Suggestion]

Comment: The [diamond operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-diamond-operator) has been in Java for 4 years. Please use it.

Comment: There is no such constructor. Use `withInitial(Supplier)` and provide the lambda there.

Comment: `ThreadLocal<Map<String, Service<Request, Response>>> connectionMapThread = ThreadLocal.withInitial(HashMap::new);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ThreadLocal<Map<String, Service<Request, Response>>> test = 
            ThreadLocal.withInitial(HashMap::new);
```

You are trying to assign a `lambda` expression to a non-functional interface, this will not work. Fortunately `ThreadLocal` offers one option with a `Supplier` via `withInitial` method